# Using rep to create an ID column

Tags: r, rep

I need to rep a sequence that has the following format:

1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,

4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,

7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, etc.

I can do something similar to this with:

```
test<- as.data.frame(rep.int(1:9, rep(1:3, each = 3)))
```

But this starts with one observation for the first three numbers instead of two. The final product I'm looking for is something close to:

```
test2<- rep.int(1:10e3, rep(1:10, each = 1e3)) # this totals to 55,000 rows 
# in the correct format, but I am looking to get a total of 54,000 rows
# and I can't figure out the right combination of arguments.
```

Any insight anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `rep(1:9, rep(1:3 + 1, each=3))`

Comment: This works for the 1:9 example, but for my data it still throws errors because following this example the code would be: `rep(1 : 9900, rep(1 : 9.9 + 1, each=1000)`, but I don't think it works due to the decimal

Comment: why would you have 1:9.9? i did not do 1:3.9 i did 1:3, you should have 1:10+1 or simply 2:11, do `rep(1:1e10, rep(2:11, each = 1e3), length = 54000)`

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong in applying it to my data, thanks for your help!